# Removing items in a collection based on listbox string

Tags: vb.net

Having issues when clicking the remove button. If more of my code is needed, let me know. I get this error on the line AddressList.Remove(selectedName):

> System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'Key' is not a valid value.

I've tried many variations but can't figure out why this doesn't work. I think it has something to do with how the strings are concatenated in the listbox. I need to be able to remove entries from the collection and the listbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Module EmailCollection
Public AddressList As New Collection

Public Sub AddRecord(ByVal a As cAddress)
    Try
        AddressList.Add(a)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: inputs must be characters valid in string format")
    End Try
End Sub

End Module
public class form1 

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim frmAdd As New AddNewName

        frmAdd.ShowDialog()

        UpdateListBox()


    End Sub
Private Sub UpdateListBox()
        lstAddress.Items.Clear()

        Dim a As cAddress
        For Each a In AddressList
            lstAddress.Items.Add(String.Concat(a.strName, a.strEmail, a.strPhone, a.strComment))
        Next

        If lstAddress.Items.Count > 0 Then
            lstAddress.SelectedIndex = 0

        End If
    End Sub
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click

        Dim selectedName As String
        Try
            ' Get the selected value.
            selectedName = lstAddress.SelectedItem.ToString()

            ' Remove the selected name from the list box and the collection.
            If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
                               "Confirm Deletion",
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then

                lstAddress.Items.Remove(selectedName)
                AddressList.Remove(selectedName)
            End If

        Catch ex As NullReferenceException
            MessageBox.Show("Select an item to remove.", "Selection Needed")
        End Try
    End Sub
end class
```

Comment: Try this: lstAddress.SelectedItem.Remove()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Module I changed `AddressList` from the old VB6 `Collection` type to the .net `List(Of T)`. The T stands for Type.

```
Module EmailCollection

    Public AddressList As New List(Of cAddress)

    Public Sub AddRecord(ByVal a As cAddress)
        AddressList.Add(a)
    End Sub

End Module
```

I guessed that your `cAddress` class looks something like this. I added a custom `.ToString` method so the list box will display the data you wish but the item, itself, will be a `cAddress` object.

```
Public Class cAddress
    Public Property strName As String
    Public Property strEmail As String
    Public Property strPhone As String
    Public Property strComment As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{strName}, {strEmail}, {strPhone}, {strComment}"
    End Function
End Class
```

In the Form...

Instead of adding a string to the list box I added the `cAddress` object. The list box calls `.ToString` on the object to get the display value.

```
Private Sub UpdateListBox()
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each a As cAddress In AddressList
        ListBox1.Items.Add(a)
    Next
    If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

In the remove button I cast the selected item to its underlying type, `cAddress`. This is the item removed from the `AddressList`. Then simply remove the selected item from the list box.

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
                           "Confirm Deletion",
                           MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        AddressList.Remove(DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, cAddress))
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End If
End Sub
```

I changed the name of the list box to `ListBox1` to match my test project.

Comment: Thank you for this. Of all the answers, this did solve my issue with the remove button. Currently working to fix my edit button now with the new list, but I believe I'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try, use a BindingSource for setting up the ListBox. In the class override ToString to what is to be shown in the ListBox rather than what you are doing now without a DataSource.

My version of your class has name and property name changes.

```
Public Class Address
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Email() As String
    Public Property Phone() As String
    Public Property Comment() As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name} {Email} {Phone} {Comment}"
    End Function
End Class
```

Mocked data is used to populate the ListBox

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly _bsAddresses As New BindingSource

    Private Sub UpdateListBox()
        Dim AddressList = New List(Of Address) From
                {
                    New Address() With {
                        .Name = "John",
                        .Email = "john@gmail.com",
                        .Phone = "555-444-3456",
                        .Comment = "AAA"},
                    New Address() With {
                        .Name = "Mary",
                        .Email = "mary@gmail.com",
                        .Phone = "888-333-2222",
                        .Comment = "BBB"},
                    New Address() With {
                        .Name = "Bob",
                        .Email = "bob@gmail.com",
                        .Phone = "111-555-9999",
                        .Comment = "CCC"}
                }

        _bsAddresses.DataSource = AddressList

        lstAddress.DataSource = _bsAddresses

        lstAddress.SelectedIndex = 0

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles Me.Shown

        UpdateListBox()

    End Sub

    Private Sub RemoveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles RemoveButton.Click

        If lstAddress.Items.Count > 0 AndAlso lstAddress.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim address = CType(_bsAddresses.Current, Address)
            If My.Dialogs.Question($"Remove {address.Name}") Then
                _bsAddresses.RemoveCurrent()
                RemoveButton.Enabled = _bsAddresses.Count > 0
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Code module for asking a question

```
Namespace My
    <ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
    Partial Friend Class _Dialogs
        Public Function Question(text As String) As Boolean
            Return (MessageBox.Show(
                text,
                My.Application.Info.Title,
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = MsgBoxResult.Yes)
        End Function
    End Class
    <HideModuleName()>
    Friend Module WinFormsDialogs
        Private instance As New ThreadSafeObjectProvider(Of _Dialogs)
        ReadOnly Property Dialogs() As _Dialogs
            Get
                Return instance.GetInstance()
            End Get
        End Property
    End Module
End Namespace
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Karen's post seems quite comprehensive.  My response is an attempt to focus on your direct question.

I don't see all of the type definitions shown in your code, but in answer to your question, which I believe is "Why am I getting System.ArgumentException: 'Argument 'Key' is not a valid value":

In the offending line of code:

```
AddressList.Remove(selectedName)
```

AddressList is a collection.  To use `.Remove`, you must pass in an object of the AddressList collection to remove it.  You are passing a simple string, and that is not an AddressList object.  You need to create an object based on your string `selectedName` to pass into `.Remove` and that line should work.  The rest of what you are doing seems more complex.